# react native tcp send byte array

Tags: react-native, tcpclient

I Have this code in c# for tcp:

```
var client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.x", 502);
var str = client.GetStream();
str.Write(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 0, 4);
byte[] recieved = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
var recievesize = str.Read(recieved, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
recieved = recieved.Take(recievesize).ToArray();
```

what is the equivalent in React native ?